# libc_hidden_proto macro in gnu library C

Tags: c, macros, glibc

in gnu library C source code, man could see some of functions prototype are followed with `libc_hidden_proto` macro, what is used for.

Answer (score 2):

> what is used for.

It's documented in `inlcude/libc-symbols.h`:

```c
/* The following macros are used for PLT bypassing within libc.so
   (and if needed other libraries similarly).
   First of all, you need to have the function prototyped somewhere,
   say in foo/foo.h:

   int foo (int __bar);

   If calls to foo within libc.so should always go to foo defined in libc.so,
   then in include/foo.h you add:

   libc_hidden_proto (foo)

   line and after the foo function definition:

   int foo (int __bar)
   {
     return __bar;
   }
   libc_hidden_def (foo)

   or

   int foo (int __bar)
   {
     return __bar;
   }
   libc_hidden_weak (foo)
```

In other words, this allows GLIBC to call e.g. `__mmap` which is defined inside `libc.so.6` *even if* you `LD_PRELOAD`ed some other library which defines its own `__mmap`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so now i have another question, are they implement this trick by renaming the function, i followed the definitions, to find out they are actually renaming the function, they concatenate it with the extension of the macro  __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__  and  __GI_

Comment: @masalkhi "I have another question ..." -- you should accept this answer and ask another question _separately_ (asking is free ;-)